# Problema con Hooks en React, no me deja imprimir datos

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

estoy teniendo un inconveniente con los Hooks de react y he buscado pero no se como solucionarlo.

El programa me lee bien los datos de Firestore, me los almacena en el SetState correctamente, pero desde el proximo componente (`ProductsList`) al cual le paso como Props el State `prodArr`, primero lo lee bien pero luego se vacia el array, no se si es por el ciclo de vida o que pero no me deja mapear para imprimir en pantalla. Dejo los console.log abajo.

BuildProduct

```
import {db} from '../../firebase';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ProductList from './ProductList';

export default function BuildProduct( {producto} ){

    const [prodArr, setProdArr] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        let retrieveProds = [];

        db.collection(producto).get().then(function(querySnapshot){
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                prodArr.push({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()});     
            });        
        })
        .catch(function(error){
                console.log('Error getting cached document: ', error);
            });
        
        setProdArr(retrieveProds);
        
        console.log('Datos almacenados en el hook: ', prodArr);

    }, []);

    return <ProductList data={prodArr} />
};
```

ProductList

```
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css';

export default function ProductList({data}){
    console.log('recibido: ', data);

    let productData = data;

    return(
        <div> {productData} </div>
    );
}
```

(en ProductList borre todo el map y eso xq no me funcionaba, quise probar almacenando el state en una variable local pero tampoco)

```
recibido:  []0: {id: "iMkOvnbQT0APIHnnSzTs", data: {…}}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
BuildProduct.jsx:23 

Datos almacenados en el hook:  []0: {id: "iMkOvnbQT0APIHnnSzTs", data: {…}}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
ProductList.jsx:4 

recibido:  []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le estás pasando un array vacio al setter del estado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y le estas haciendo push al estado directamente..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que pienso yo que deberias hacer es:

```
    const [prodArr, setProdArr] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        // la coleccion es asincrona por eso debes meter la logica dentro del then:
        db.collection(producto).get().then(function(querySnapshot){
            let retrieveProds = [];
            retrieveProds.forEach(function(doc){
                // añades a retrieveProds en lugar de prodArr
                retrieveProds.push({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()});     
            });
            setProdArr(retrieveProds); // redefines el estado   
        })
        .catch(function(error){
                console.log('Error getting cached document: ', error);
            });
        
        console.log('Datos almacenados en el hook: ', prodArr);

    }, []);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! me funciono, no me di cuenta que cambie el nombre del array!